# removing words but not numbers from a text file in python

Tags: python

There is one column and within that column, there may or may not be 1 to many 6 digit numbers. The data must remain in the order it is listed in the original worksheet for example A1 must stay in row 1, row 2 row 2 and so on.

For example:

```
Cell A1:
Lipodystrophy: congenital generalized: type 2: 269700; Encephalopathy: progressive: with or without lipodystrophy: 615924; Silver spastic paraplegia syndrome: 270685; and Neuropathy: distal hereditary motor: type VA: 600794
```

Becomes:

```
269700, 615924, 270685, 600794
```

Comment: What is your input format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one liner;

```
in_string = ("Lipodystrophy: congenital generalized: type 2: 269700; "
             "Encephalopathy: progressive: with or without lipodystrophy: "
             "615924; Silver spastic paraplegia syndrome: 270685; "
             "and Neuropathy: distal hereditary motor: type VA: 600794")

output = ', '.join([word for word in in_string.replace(';', '').split()
                    if word.isdigit()])
```

Outputs;

```
print(output)
>>> 269700, 615924, 270685, 600794
```

---

Alternatively, using an input file;

```
 with open('input.csv') as fin, open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    output = '\n'.join(','.join(word for word in line.replace(';', '').split() 
                                if word.isdigit()) for line in fin)
    fout.write(output)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what 'put it inside a this' means?

Comment: `csv_in.replace` won't work because `csv_in` is not a string.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include that in just a second

Comment: You don't need to use the CSV module. You also shouldn't specify the data input as `'wb'` as you're not writing bytes. I've updated my answer now to fit your use case using the csv files

Comment: @a.mah edited my answer now to output as a single column.

Comment: I'm confused what you want - do you want a column of the numbers from each line?

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expression](https://regexone.com/references/python).

```
import csv 
import re 

with open('input.csv') as fin, 
open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout: 
    csv_in = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = '\t')
    csv_out = csv.writer(fout) 
    for row in csv_in: 
        matchList = re.findall(r'\d{6}', row, flags=0)
        csv_out.writerow(matchList)
```

pattern will be like "\d{6}" or "/d/d/d/d/d/d"

Comment: import csv
import re
with open('input.csv') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csv_in = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = '\t')
    csv_out = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv_in:
        result = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', row)

    csv_out.writerow(row)